# Junit test case doesn't work as expected

Tags: java, junit

I have the following jUnit test case for testing exponentiation

```
@Test
public void testExponentiation() {
    AssertSame("Not valid!",32.0,this.myObject.expo(2,5))
}
```

and my expo function is

```
public double expo(int n1,int n2) {
    return Math.pow(n1,n2);
}
```

This doesn't work as expected ,but `AssertSame` works well with Integer primitive types.Can someone explain why?

Comment: Here's a guess, when you're doing Maths with doubles you don't get exact decimcal values. So what you might be getting is something like 32.000000000001 and that's not exactly the same as 32.0

Comment: @Ankur If I use Sysout(Math.pow(2,5)); it prints 32.0

Answer (score 6):

There are two bugs in your code:

First, `assertSame()` can only be used to determine whether the two parameters refer to the **same object** (eg. the references are equal, like it would by using operator `==`), and it works only for reference types ([see the Javadoc](http://junit.sourceforge.net/junit3.8.1/javadoc/junit/framework/Assert.html#assertSame%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29)). In your case, your exponential method returns a value type (`double`), and the expected result you passed to the `assertSame()` method is also a value type (`float`).

When Java finds a value type anywhere it expects a reference type, it performs *autoboxing* ([you can read about it here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html)), thus creates a new instance of the reference type that matches the value type (for example `Float` for `float`). In your case, this is what basically happens in the background:

```
assertSame("Not valid!", new Double(32.0), new Double(this.myObject.expo(2,5)))
```

or to be more precise:

```
assertSame("Not valid!", Double.valueOf(32.0), Double.valueOf(this.myObject.expo(2,5)))
```

From this, you can clearly see, that these two references will never be the same, as they are two different objects. For comparing values you have to use one of the `assertEquals()` methods.

The second bug is that the other answers say, because of the limited precision of the floating point numbers, you have to compare them with some tolerance (or delta). Fortunately, you don't have to do it manually for each float comparison, because JUnit provides you with the perfect `assertEquals()` method for this purpose ([here's the Javadoc](http://junit.sourceforge.net/junit3.8.1/javadoc/junit/framework/Assert.html#assertEquals%28java.lang.String,%20float,%20float,%20float%29)):

```
public static void assertEquals(java.lang.String message,
                                float expected,
                                float actual,
                                float delta)
```

It expects an expected value, an actual value and a tolerance it should use for comparing the expected and actual values. If you use this method, your code would look like this:

```
@Test
public void testExponentiation() {
    assertEquals("Not valid!", 32.0, this.myObject.expo(2,5), 1e-5);
}
```

And hopefully it will successfully run and pass the test.

**EDIT**: The reason why `assertSame()` worked for you for integer numbers is that Java caches integers from -128 to 127 to save memory. This means that calling `Integer.valueOf(5)` will always return the same `Integer` instance, therefore their references will be equal. Try this little example:

```
Integer i1 = 6;                   // Autoboxing, Integer.valueof(6)
Integer i2 = Integer.valueOf(6);
Integer i3 = new Integer(6);

i1 == i2;      // True, their references are the same
i2 == i3;      // False
i1 == i3;      // False
```